# Método de login sempre retorna false

Tags: java

Criei um método que retorna um valor boolean para acesso em um programa que estou fazendo. Se o usuário conseguir efetuar login, então retorna `true`, se não, retorna `false`. Porém está sempre retornando `false`, independente se o login e senha estão certos, e não estou entendendo o porquê.

Usei `JOptionPane` pois quis umas interações com o usuário melhor do que simplesmente usando `System.out.print`

```
   List<String> user = new ArrayList<>();
   List<String> pass = new ArrayList<>();

    //Aqui tem um código onde insiro valores nos ArrayList user e pass. 
    //Que por sinal aparentemente está correto. Printei os arraylist pra ter certeza disso
    //Não coloquei nesse post pois é meio grande.


    public boolean login() {
    String log = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o login");
    System.out.println("login digitado: "+log);
    String pas = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite a senha");
    System.out.println("Senha digitada: "+pas);
    for (String c : user) {
        System.out.println("valor de 'c' : "+c); 
        //aqui ele printa o valor de 'c'(login), e por sinal esta correto 
        if (c == log) { 
        //mesmo se atribuir o valor correto a 'log' e ele for igual a 'c' o programa não lê este 'if'

            System.out.println("usuario valido"); //isso ñ printa
            for (String s : pass) {
                if (s == pas) {
                    System.out.println("senha válida");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("incompativel senha");
        }
        System.out.println("incompativel login"); //por fim, ele printa isso
    }
    // e sempre retorna false
    return false; //independente se o usuario digitou tudo certo ou ñ
}
```

Por que não está funcionando esse sistema de login?

Comment: Acho que tu lógica foi pro brejo. Ex: Usuario 1 - Senha 123, Usuario 2 - senha 456. Agora loga com Usuario: Usuário 1 e coloca a senha 456 hehehe. Acho que alguem logou com uma senha que não te pertence hehehe

Comment: Boa tarde Felipe, seja bem vindo a Stack Overflow em Portugues, recomendo que da proxima vez faça titulos mais intuitivos ao problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao invés de `if(s == pass)`,  faça: `if(s.equals(pass))`.

Mesma coisa para:

```
if(c == log)
```

Faça:

```
if(c.equals(log))
```

Comment: Bom, deixando um pouco mais claro, oq o Luiz fez acima é o correto, para comparar uma string, é sempre equals, o "==" para o resto, inteiro, real, booleano e outros.

Comment: @Luiz muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @BrunoGomes valeu pela explicação! ^^